# Interpreting cmp followed by test

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I am trying to understand this code (I replaced addresses with lab1 etc.):

```
cmpb $0x7f, %al             ; 127
je lab1              
testb $0x7f, %al            ; 127
jne lab2             
lab1:  testb $0x7f, %al            ; 127
je lab3
```

First it is checked if `al` is equal to 127. In either case`testb` is called. I do not understand the purpose of this check. `test` performs a bitwise AND. The result will be zero if al has the bits of 127 inverted. The code is called after `waitpid` returns, maybe it is related to this.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't make sense if you already know the value equals `0x7f`. Otherwise, it can be used to test if any of the low 7 bits are set.

Comment: If the jump to `lab1` is taken, the jump to `lab3` will never be taken. And if the jumps to `lab1` and `lab2` are not taken, the jump to `lab3` will always be taken. So the last test is useless in all cases.

Comment: *The result will be zero if al has the bits of 127 inverted* - Maybe it becomes more understandable saying "The result will be **not**-zero if any bit of the seven right bits (bit8 doesn't matter) of `AL` is set, in this case `jne lab2` jumps and `je lab3` does **not** jump". Consider that `lab1` is executed if `AL==0x7F` **and** also if `AL==0x00 | AL==0x80`.

Comment: This looks like a short delay intended to wait for some piece of hardware to finish. Or AL is modified outside our view, e.g. by an interrupt.